# sql query with complicated join to get unique records list

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need a query that select customer table with right cardId by applied the below cases.

If you have any suggestions, please share.

Possible cases are:

1. Only one records found - easy, use the Card_id found
2. No records found - leave blank
3. More than one record found - use the Card_id that starts with 2000 if available, otherwise pick the one with latest created date (in CustomerCards table)

Customer Table:

```
ID        CardID
1         200132
2         263987
3         100789
..
```

CustomerCards table

```
CustomerId         CardID        CreatedOn
1                  209890        12/11/2014
1                  200132        12/12/2014 
1                  100732        11/10/2014
2                  168902        12/11/2014
2                  263987        15/01/2015
```

I've started with left join:

```
select ct.* from dbo.Customer ct
left join dbo.CustomerCard cc
on ct.id = cc.customerId
```

And a bit stuck after that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us query and explain what's wrong with it!

Comment: You might want to look at [Case-When](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) for adding if-then-else type of logic.

Answer (score 1):

A start

```
;with cte1 as
(
select cc.CustomerId, cc.CardID, cc.CreatedOn
  from dbo.CustomerCard cc
 group by cc.CustomerId, cc.CardID, cc.CreatedOn 
having count(*) = 1
), cte200 as
(
select cc.CustomerId, cc.CardID, max(cc.CreatedOn)
  from dbo.CustomerCard cc
 group by cc.CustomerId, cc.CardID 
 where cc.CardID like '2000%'
)
select cte1
union
select cte2000 
union 
select ct.ID, ct.CardID, '1/1/1900' as  CreatedOn
  from dbo.Customer ct
  left join dbo.CustomerCard cc
    on ct.id = cc.customerId
 where cc.customerId is null 
union 
select cc.ID, cc.CardID, max(cc.CreatedOn)
  from dbo.CustomerCard cc 
  left join cte1  
    on cte1.customerId    = cc.customerId
  left join cte2000  
    on cte2000.customerId = cc.customerId
 where cte1.customerId    is null 
   and cte2000.customerId is null
 group by cc.ID, cc.CardID
```